# JSON array and object in Android

Tags: android, json

Parsing JSON array and object in Android
json:https://api.adjaranet.com/api/v1/movies/
I am trying to parse it with the following Java code in Android but unlimited loading when add
moviejson.getJSONObject("genres").getJSONObject("data").getString("primaryName")

half code is

```
 try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
            JSONArray jsonArray =  jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
            
            for(int i =0;i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject moviejson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            
                //if (moviejson.getJSONObject("plot").getJSONObject("data").getString("language").equals("GEO")){
                arrayList.add(new MovieItem(
                                      moviejson.getString("id"),
                                      moviejson.getJSONObject("posters").getJSONObject("data").getString("240"),
                                      moviejson.getString("primaryName"),
                                      moviejson.getString("secondaryName"),
                                      moviejson.getString("year"),
                                      moviejson.getJSONObject("plot").getJSONObject("data").getString("description"),
                                      moviejson.getJSONObject("rating").getJSONObject("imdb").getString("score"),
                                      moviejson.getJSONObject("covers").getJSONObject("data").getString("1920"),
                                  moviejson.getJSONObject("genres").getJSONObject("data").getString("primaryName")
                              ));
                    
                //}
                loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

How solve this problem?

Comment: Can you post an example of JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your json content, `data` inside `genres` is an array, not object. That's why when you are trying to parse `moviejson.getJSONObject("genres").getJSONObject("data")` it throws error.

[image]

Try

```
String genreString = "";
int length = moviejson.getJSONObject("genres").getJSONArray("data").length();
for(int j =0 ; j < length ; j++) {
    genreString += moviejson.getJSONObject("genres").getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(j).getString("primaryName");
}
```

Comment: how connect primaryName

Comment: moviejson.getJSONObject("genres").getJSONArray("data").getstring dont work

Comment: i can parse genres--> data

Comment: `data` is an array. You have to iterate through the json array. `getString()` only works for json object.

Comment: i need genres-data-primaryName

Comment: There are several `primaryName`. Which one do you want?

Comment: data--genres--data--primaryName

Comment: all primaryName in genres in one string

Comment: I've added an image to this answer. Please check that and tell me which primaryName do you want? There are two primaryName inside genre -> data.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: genres--data are dinamicaly, its changed Changing with movies :) Sometimes there are two objects, sometimes five :)

Comment: Please share updated code in https://pastebin.com/ and give the link here.

Comment: Sorry, key name was typed wrong. Updated the answer.

Comment: ya its work , how can i To highlight ex "primaryName , PrimaryName"?

Comment: thanks, can you tell me how make space Between primaryName?

Comment: Try `genreString += " " + moviejson.getJSONObject("genres").getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(j).getString("primaryName");`